# How to use exception to handle array size input and elements which can be used to calculate average?

Tags: java, oop

My program will allow user to enter array size and elements inside the array. My problem is when a negative array size number is entered, it still continues to enter elements and not the InputMismatchException which will the  prompt the user to enter again. I'm new to Java and please help me out

public class Lab5Class {

```
    public static double avgArry(double[] a) {
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;

        for(double numbers: a) {
            sum+=numbers;
            average = sum / a.length;
        }

        return average;
}   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       int attempt = 1;
       int size;

    do {  
       try {
           System.out.println("Enter the size of the array : ");
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            size = input.nextInt();
           double myArray[] = new double[size];
         System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array one by one: " );
           for(int i = 0;i<size; i++) {
           myArray[i] = input.nextDouble();
           }
           System.out.println("Contents of the array are: "+Arrays.toString(myArray));
           attempt++;
       }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
           System.out.println("Invalid Input! Please try again");
       }
       }while(attempt == 1); 

}
}
```

Comment: use Exception to handle array size? why would you want to use Exceptions for that?

Comment: If you REALLY want to use exception for that, you need to throw them yourself, eg: `throw new InputMismatchException("some message)`. With that being said, you shouldn't use Exception for controlling flow of your application, incorrect inpus is expected, you should simply validate it and ask again.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use a negative integer as size, the size of an array represents the number of elements in it.

Still if you do so, the program gets compiled without issues but, while executing it generates a runtime exception of type NegativeArraySizeException

Example:

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] intArray = new int[-5];
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
```

Comment: But my questions want an InputMismatchException

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Refactor to your needs

```
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      boolean flag;
      do {
        double temp = input.nextDouble();
        if (temp < 0) {
          System.err.println("Number must be greater than zero");
          flag = false;
        } else {
          myArray[i] = temp;
          flag = true;
        }
      } while (!flag);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just combine an if statement and a while-loop instead, like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int attempt = 1;
    int size;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean correctSize = false;

    System.out.print("Enter the size of the array : ");
    size = input.nextInt();
    if (size <= 0) {
        while (!correctSize) {
            System.out.print("ERROR:Size cannot be less than zero, please enter a number greater than zero:");
            size = input.nextInt();
            if (size > 0) {
                correctSize = true;
            }
        }
    }

    double myArray[] = new double[size];
    System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array one by one: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        myArray[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }
    System.out.println("Contents of the array are: " + Arrays.toString(myArray));
    attempt++;

}
```

There is an exception called "NegativeArraySizeException" but you wouldn't want to use that since the user should be prompted to enter the size again. Refer to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/can-you-pass-the-negative-number-as-an-array-size-in-java) website if you want to know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

See below implementation of your `Lab5Class`. It asks the user to re-enter values that aren't numbers (by catching `InputMismatchException`). It also keeps asking the user to enter the array size, until [s]he enters a positive number. After all the required values are entered, it displays the array contents and the average.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab5Class {
    public static double avgArry(double[] a) {
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;

        for (double numbers : a) {
            sum += numbers;
            average = sum / a.length;
        }

        return average;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = 0;
        while (size <= 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter the size of the array: ");
            try {
                size = input.nextInt();
                if (size <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("   Size must be positive. PLease try again.");
                }
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("   Invalid Input! Please try again");
            }
            input.nextLine();
        }
        double myArray[] = new double[size];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array one by one: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter element " + i + ": ");
            try {
                myArray[i] = input.nextDouble();
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                i--;
                System.out.println("   Invalid Input! Please try again");
            }
            input.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Contents of the array are: " + Arrays.toString(myArray));
        System.out.println("average = " + avgArry(myArray));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must throw an exception then after

```
 size = input.nextInt();
```

add

```
if (size <= 0) {
    throw new InputMismatchException("Array size must be larger than 0");
}
```